# Gravity property not working in SpriteKit Scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
 }

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event:            UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Beach Ball-100")
        self.addChild(sprite)

        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = location
        sprite.color = UIColor.redColor()
        sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect:self.frame)
        sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        var action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

  }
  }

  }
```

The code above is present in my scene class. When I run it, the ball object is not falling as expected since the gravity property is set to true. Please explain what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Physicsbody is wrong. You need the frame of the sprite and not of the world:

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.frame.size)
```

Comment: Stefan, Thanks for the reply. I used circleOfRadius and it started working.

Comment: By the way, if I want to add collision detection i.e., I want the ball to bounce after reaching the bottom of the screen. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear. Happy coding

Comment: You have to add additional sprites and collision bit masks. Here is a good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/84341/create-breakout-game-sprite-kit-swift

Comment: Thank you Stefan .. it was very helpful. So, every time we need to have borders at the edges of the screen, i can use the following code?                   let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
// 2. Set the friction of that physicsBody to 0
borderBody.friction = 0
// 3. Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody
self.physicsBody = borderBody

Answer (score 1):

Add `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate
```

Define your `physicsWorld` in `didMoveToView` or in `touchesBegan`(like you did in example)

```
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -1.0)
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Give your node proper `SKPhysicsBody` size

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: frame.size.width / 2)
```